# Can't figure out why <span> jumps to next line (svelte material ui)

Tags: html, css, svelte

```
<FormField style="display: inline;">
    <Checkbox />
    <span slot="label">test</span>
</FormField>


<script lang="ts">
    import FormField from '@smui/form-field';
    import Checkbox from '@smui/checkbox';
</script>
```

I'm trying to create a list of checkboxes with labels beside them, but the labels are jumping to the next line. I really can't figure out why.

Shouldn't the inline take care of this?

I'm using the svelte material ui btw.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably forgotten to import the css file for the material ui component. You need to import css file for each one of them.

```
import '@smui/checkbox/bare.css'
import '@smui/form-field/bare.css'
...
```

Add these lines to your top-level component inside the `<script>` tag, so these css styles will be available in all the nested components. I am not sure if there is a way to import all css files at once though.

Comment: thanks! Really annoying that it doesn't import automatically...

Answer (score 2):

The `display:inline` should not be on the `<Formfield>`, it needs to be on the two elements that are siblings (usually, your checkbox and the span).

BUT your checkbox is not a `<input type="checkbox" />` element, it is a component. Therefore, you must check inside the component and see what code is in there. Perhaps the checkbox is surrounded by a div? What is being output into the DOM (use DevTools F12 to check what html is rendered)

A solution is to use flexbox on the `<Formfield>` element. Instead of `display:inline`, try using `display:flex` -- that alone might fix your problem.

Some useful links for quick flexbox info:

https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc